# Unexpected end of input error which comes very first time using DiskDB

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, node-modules

I am working on node js application and using `Diskdb` as database. It gives error on very first time as follows:

```
undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

In documentation I found solution of this as "please make sure it contains a valid JSON array, otherwise `diskDB` will return an empty array." So can any one suggest me how can I check this file contains json array or not?

I am loading collection using

```
db.loadCollections(['users']);
var u = db.users.findOne();
console.log(u); // []
```

How can I check [] exists or not in file?

One more question is there how can I test record exists or not with multiple conditions in diskdb.

e.g. in users.json contains

```
[{"email":"noname@email.com","password":"123","status":"1","_id":"e39a62a9c7b94d76892f9c3bdfa22715"}]
```

and my code using which i am checking is as follows:

```
 db.loadCollections(['users']);

 var preCheck = db.users.find({"email" : req.body.email,"password" : req.body.password});
    if(preCheck !== undefined){

        if( (preCheck.email == req.body.email) && (preCheck.password == req.body.password) ){ 
            //logged in

            req.session.email = req.body.email;
            req.session.userId = preCheck._id;
            req.flash('success','Successful Login');
            res.redirect('/option');
        }
        else{

            req.flash('error','Email Id or Password is Incorrect');
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    }
```

but it does not allow me to login.

Thanks!

Comment: `db.users.find` returns array, try `findOne`

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps you.

```
var db = require('diskdb');
db = db.connect('data', ['users']);  // it connects and loads the collection

var preCheck = db.users.findOne({
    "email"    : req.body.email,
    "password" : req.body.password
});

if(preCheck){
   //logged in
   req.session.email = req.body.email;
   req.session.userId = preCheck._id;
   req.flash('success','Successful Login');
   res.redirect('/option');
} else{
   req.flash('error','Email Id or Password is Incorrect');
   res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer. It should work. It is working in my case.

Comment: [{"email":"noname@email.com","password":"123","status":"1","_id":"9901864955484f1ab89153b8c39ee496"},
{"email":"noname@email.com123","password":"123456","status":"1","_id":"62fa6458824946bc8a614a463e04151f"}] is in my users.json but it allows login for abc@rest.com and password 123

Comment: Query is working as AND. And, it is not working for partial match.

Comment: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined, if I applied wrong credentials, and worked if email wrong and password correct of first record.

Answer (score 0):

As your DB will either empty or contains the following `json` data.

```
[{"email":"noname@email.com","password":"123","status":"1","_id":"e39a62a9c7b94d76892f9c3bdfa22715"}]
```

`findOne()` only shows first row of record of your collection. You can either filter this or not, it depends upon your requirements.

Use the `find()` in your Code, which you are already using:

```
var preCheck = db.users.find({"email" : req.body.email,"password" : req.body.password});
if(preCheck.length !== 0){
  if( (preCheck[0].email == req.body.email) && (preCheck[0].password == req.body.password) ){ 
           
    req.session.email = req.body.email;
    req.session.userId = preCheck[0]._id;
    req.flash('success','Successful Login');
    res.redirect('/option');
  }
  else{
     req.flash('error','Email Id or Password is Incorrect');
     res.redirect('/login');
  }
}
else{
req.flash('error','Email Id or Password is Incorrect');
res.redirect('/login');
}
```

As data will be in array of json so use `preCheck[0]` there to get the data. Your query is working as `AND` condition. For more details, you can check its [GitHub Link](https://github.com/arvindr21/diskdb).

Note: I suggest to use [sqllite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) as database. It's asynchronous (almost a must-have), it's the most actively maintained, and it has the most stars on GitHub. You can get the tutorial at [this Link.](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004094234/https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/node-sqlite-tutorial/)

Comment: Will this create empty array default in my collection ?

Comment: yes, when you call the `db.loadCollections(['users']);` it will create collection json file as well empty array in that.